# "ViewHolder views must not be attached when created"- RecyclerView with ArrayList

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to Android and Android Studio.
I am trying to get a recyclerview with arraylist but getting the error "ViewHolder views must not be attached when created".
This is the first time I am trying to implement RecyclerView. First I am trying to get static data into the layout, but later I want to get the data from Database and show it dynamically on the activity.

Main Activity:-

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerview;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar  = findViewById(R.id.main_actionbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product1","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product2","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product3","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product4","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product5","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product6","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product7","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product8","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product9","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product10","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product11","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_search_black_24dp,"Product12","Description", "Bla Bla Bla", "Bla Bla Bla"));

        mRecyclerview = findViewById(R.id.main_recyclerview);
        mRecyclerview.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new ExampleAdpater(exampleList);

        mRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.sample_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Example Code (class):-

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class ExampleItem {
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mText1;
    private String mText2;
    private String mText3;
    private String mText4;

    public ExampleItem(int imageResource, String text1, String text2, String text3, String text4){
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
        mText2 = text2;
        mText3 = text3;
        mText4 = text4;

    }

    public int getImageResource(){
        return  mImageResource;
    }

    public String getText1(){
        return mText1;
    }

    public String getText2(){
        return mText2;
    }

    public String getText3(){
        return mText3;
    }

    public String getText4(){
        return mText4;
    }
}
```

ExampleAdapter (class):-

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ExampleAdpater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdpater.ExampleviewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<ExampleItem> mExampleList;

    public static class  ExampleviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public ImageView mImageView;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mTextView2;
        public TextView mTextView3;
        public TextView mTextView4;

        public ExampleviewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myImageView1);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView1);
            mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView2);
            mTextView3 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView3);
            mTextView4 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myTextView4);
        }
    }

    public ExampleAdpater(ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList){
        mExampleList = exampleList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ExampleviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent);
        ExampleviewHolder evh = new ExampleviewHolder(v);
        return  evh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleviewHolder holder, int position) {
        ExampleItem currentItem = mExampleList.get(position);

        holder.mImageView.setImageResource(currentItem.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentItem.getText1());
        holder.mTextView2.setText(currentItem.getText2());
        holder.mTextView3.setText(currentItem.getText3());
        holder.mTextView4.setText(currentItem.getText4());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mExampleList.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass **false** to  2nd argument of inflate method.

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, false);
```

Comment: Didn't work by providing "false" as second argument. But it worked by passing "false" as third argument.

Comment: @SamarpitShrivastava oops..my mistake..happy coding

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent);
> ```

This will implicitly add the inflated item to `parent`. You shouldn't do that with RecyclerView.

Use

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
```

to not add it to the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the boolean `false` for attach to root as a parameter in your `onCreateViewHolder`.
i.e.

```java
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

use oncreate --

```
@Override
public ExampleviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.example_item,parent, false);
    ExampleviewHolder evh = new ExampleviewHolder(v);
    return  evh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  return new ExempleViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_pub, parent, false));
```

and

```
 this.mExampleList = exampleList;
```